# List of dicts unable to extract values using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list like this one:

```
l1 = [{'a': 123, 'b': 128}, {'a': 998, 'b': 345}]
```

I would like to create another list that contains only the `a` values:
example:

```
[123,998]
```

I try this:

```
[x,i for x in l1[i]]
```

but I get an error. Then i try this:

```
[x for x in l1[x]]
```

and this:

```
[x[0] for x in l1]
```

but nothing. I can't create the expected final result.

Comment: When working with dictionaries you need to access the key's values with their key-names and not their index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over `l1` and access `'a'` from each element:

```
l1 = [{'a': 123, 'b': 128}, {'a': 998, 'b': 345}]
a_list = [i['a'] for i in l1]
```

Output:

```
[123, 998]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the explicit way of achieving your goal

```
l1 = [{'a': 123, 'b': 128}, {'a': 998, 'b': 345}]

alist = []
for dic in l1:
       alist.append(dic['a'])

print(alist)
```

iterate through the list of dictionaries and append key a to a new list